# How to manage application startup?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, security, authentication

We are developing an application for customer, include Windows App, MacOS App and Linux app.

The app is basically a single execute file, and is able to run normally if copied to other Windows/Mac/Linux machine. The customer needs to prevent this kind of thing, needs to control who can use the app.

So my idea to solve this problem on Linux is to create a `/etc/.random1/.random2/.random3` with a fixed string like `5esd5s`, when the app runs it will first read that file and check the content, and exits if not match.

But if someone find out that file, he can easily create a same file in another machine and run that app.

And I completely have no idea how to solve that on Windows and Mac.

How to solve this kind of problem? Even keywords for Google is OK, I'm poor of English, cannot find out any useful information with my words in Google.

Answer (score 0):

You should try tokens. For example, create a random token and put it in two different files, and when you start the application, verify that they are identical in both files.

It's a simple thought

Comment: But if someone finds out these two files and copy them to another machine, I think the app can still run. How to prevent that?

Comment: with password encrypted in the files

Answer (score 0):

as Ubunter said try tokens and generate your tokens using username or hostname, validate it then you can prevent running same app on another machine